# Laravel - Passing multiple columns of data to a select tag label

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following the tutorial about Laravel and I'm now on the part where the example is about selecting multiple tags for an article. So it's a many-to-many relationship.

I've been trying to pass multiple data to each item to a select tag for the label then it's value. I have to display a student full name but my database divided the name into first, middle and last. Originally, this is my controller code:

```
public function create()
{
    $students = Student::lists(['first_name', 'id');

    return view('cases.create', compact('students'));
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
public function create()
{
    $students = Student::lists(['first_name', 'last_name'], 'id');

    return view('cases.create', compact('students'));
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 1535:
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I think that it wouldn't allow me to pass a string. So, do I have to create another variable to store the last_name then concatenate it in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent ORM provides `toJson()` method which will convert your resultset from an `array` to a `json`. Try the following

`$students = Student::lists(['first_name', 'last_name'], 'id')->toJson();`

Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for answering, i tried it but it didn't solve the issue. Still getting the error: 

    ErrorException in Builder.php line 1535:
    strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: try this -> `$students = Student::lists('first_name', 'last_name', 'id')->toJson();` . you were passing an array `['first_name', 'last_name']` in the `lists` method.  That was throwing an exception.

Comment: Three more errors:  

ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 418:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mnhs-project\resources\views\cases\form.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mnhs-project\resources\views\cases\form.blade.php)  

ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 418:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mnhs-project\resources\views\cases\form.blade.php)  

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Now the query seems okay. This may be the error in the for each of your form. Data retrieved from the database is in the json form. Convert it into an array and then put it inside your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

The `lists` method would throw an exception if you pass an array to it. 
(*and not sure whether passing in strings separated by commas would give the expected result in your case as I wasn't able to find anything in the Laravel documentation on this*).

The following should do the trick for you, *using the `all` method instead*:

```
$students = Students::all(['id', DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as full_name'])->toArray();
```

Here, you'll be passing an array of `columns` that you need in the result set. 
But before you are able to use the `list` of students in your view, you'll need to make *a little tweak* on the initial list that you have (*in case you want to use it with `Form::select()` method*):

```
$list = [];
foreach($students as $student){
     $list[$student['id']] = $student['full_name'];
}
```

Now, you can pass this `array` to the view and populate the `select` element.

Comment: The 'all' method displays a full name but because it returns an array, the select list would look like each item passed to the select list is divided into 3 parts: 0, ExampleFName ExampleLName, ExampleID. I can select them separately. I tried to remove the ->toArray() method then it displays them as a whole, but the problem now is that the value of each item stays in default(0,1,2,3...) that should be the 'id'. And also it's not that clean because the '{' is visible in the label and also the 'full_name' can be seen.

Comment: Do you want a key value pair like `id => full_name`?

Comment: If yes, then after querying the model (_as I've done in the answer_) ***refine*** the list of students as specified at the end of this answer. Thus, you'll take the `id` of a particular student as the `key` of the array, and **map** it to the `CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name)` (concatenation of the two column values) that is the _full name_ of the student.